# xevent.xkey.keycode not working for me (X11)

Tags: c, input, x11

So I have this piece of code which works well

```
while(1) {
    XNextEvent(dpy,&e);
    paint(cs,g);
    if(e.xbutton.button == 1) {
        evolue(g,gc,cycleG);
        paint(cs,g);
        printf("test");
    }else if(e.xbutton.button==3) break ;
}
```

here xbutton.button == 1 is the left click.

I want to change the code so that it does the function with a keyboard press by changing it to

```
while(1) {
    XNextEvent(dpy,&e);
    paint(cs,g);
    if(e.xkey.keycode == 54) {
        evolue(g,gc,cycleG);
        paint(cs,g);
        printf("test");
    }else if(e.xbutton.button==3) break ;
}
```

I got the keycode 54 by running xev on the terminal

so anyways logically the second piece of code should work but it just doesn't run the code inside the if statement unlike when it took mouse input. So..what gives? And how to fix it taking keyboard input?

Edit:
for further testing I wrote this code

```
while(1) {
    XNextEvent(dpy,&e);
    
    if(e.type == KeyPress){
        paint(cs,g);
        evolue(g,gc,cycleG);
    }
    
    if(e.type == ButtonPress){
        paint(cs,g);
        evolue(g,gc,cycleG);
    }
}
```

so that it executes the program no matter what mouse button is pressed and no matter what keyboard key is pressed, but again, only mouse buttons execute the program while keyboard keys dont.

Comment: Apart from anything else you never check the [`type` of event](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xevent) processed by `XNextEvent`.

Comment: @G.M. but isn't Xevent applicable for all event types?

Comment: `XEvent` is a union of structs with each struct beginning with the field `int type`.  The `type` field is used to discriminate the union.  See e.g. [this example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X_Window_Programming/Xlib#Example).

Comment: @G.M. I modified my post to show further testing I did, so that it checks what Xevent type it is and it is still not working

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @G.M. While I was trying to create the minimal reproducible example I realised the error. Thanks a lot for the help I probably would've given up otherwise

Comment: The title tells nothing about the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in a function above that chooses the input type it was this

```
XSelectInput(dpy, win, ExposureMask|ButtonPressMask);
```

I changed it to this

```
XSelectInput(dpy, win, ExposureMask|ButtonPressMask|KeyPressMask);
```

and this fixed it.